# How to show Open/Closed based on two shift working hours on website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display Open or Closed based on a shift (two Shifts daily) using Javascript. I want to be able to use that data which is stored within a span and then determine if the business is open or closed and display that.  for me only one shift is working during second shift its displaying We are now closed.
Might be something better to do the same but only in HTML.
any other suggestion is appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far:

```js
function isOpen(timeRangeEl, date) {
    var day = '' + date.getDay();
    var hhmm = ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

    var days = timeRangeEl.getAttribute('data-days');
    var openTime = timeRangeEl.getAttribute('data-open');
    var closeTime = timeRangeEl.getAttribute('data-close');
    return days.indexOf(day) >= 0 && openTime <= hhmm && hhmm < closeTime;
}

function openClose() {
    var date = new Date();
    var display = document.getElementById('open-display');
    var els = display.getElementsByClassName('timerange');
    var anyActive = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        if (isOpen(els[i], date)) {
            anyActive = true;
            els[i].className = els[i].className.replace(/ *inactive\b/g, '');
        } else if (els[i].className.indexOf('inactive') < 0) {
            els[i].className += ' inactive';
        }
    }
    if (anyActive) {
        display.className = 'open';
    } else {
        display.className = 'closed';
    }
}

setInterval(openClose, 5000);
openClose();
```

```css
#open-display.open > .timerange.inactive,
#open-display.open > .timerange2.inactive,
#open-display.open .days {
     display: none;
}
#open-display.open > .openclosed::before {
    content: 'We are now Open';
}
#open-display.closed > .openclosed::before {
    content: 'We are now Closed';
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
<h3>Working Hours</h3>
<div id="open-display">
 <div class="openclosed"></div>
 <div class="timerange" data-days="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31" data-open="12:30" data-close="15:30"><span class="days">Noon</span> 12:30pm - 3:30pm</div>
 <div class="timerange2" data-days="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31" data-open="18:00" data-close="00:30"><span class="days">Dine</span> 6:00pm - 12:30am</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Successfully done after trying and doing trial and error method.